# VerticalCenter not working as expected?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I've been playing with laying out some simple shapes inside groups in Flex and I seem to be able to build scenarios where verticalCenter doesn't do a perfect job at centering things. If you run the snippet below and move the HSlider towards the left you should be able to notice that the diamond is not always vertically centered with respect to the Rect. This is particularly clear when you get to the diamond is slightly larger than the rect - in which case the bottom tip sticks out while the top one doesn't.

Am I doing something horribly wrong, or am I just hitting against pixel resolution? Or what else?

would love any advice!

thank you.

POST EDIT: adding another example, even simpler, that shows this again. Looks like pixel resolution to me...

---- main.mxml ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">

    <s:Group height="{hs.value}" width="80" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
        <s:Rect height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0x787878"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
        <local:diamond verticalCenter="0" height="100%"/>
    </s:Group>
    <s:HSlider maximum="40" value="30" id="hs"/>
</s:Application>
```

---- diamond.mxml ------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:Group height="100%" verticalCenter="0" scaleY="0.70">
        <s:Path verticalCenter="0"
                data="M 7.847 19.31 
                L 7.842 19.312 
                L 0 11.47 
                L 11.468 0 
                L 15.107 3.64 
                L 15.112 3.638 
                L 22.94 11.467 
                L 11.472 22.935 
                L 7.847 19.31 Z" >
            <s:fill>
                <s:LinearGradient rotation="90" scaleX="49.3475" x="11.47" y="-0.308">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="#FFD500" ratio="0"/>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="#F5A106" ratio="1"/>
                </s:LinearGradient>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Path>
    </s:Group>
</s:Group>
```

-------------------------- NEW EXAMPLE ----------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="600" minHeight="400">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Group horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" width="80" height="40">
        <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0xdddddd"/>                
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <s:Rect height="33" width="80" verticalCenter="0">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFF99"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

the inner rectangle is not vertically centered in the outer one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last example, you have a 40 pixel high group that has a 33 pixel high rectangle within it, that makes 7 pixels in between that needs to be divided by 2 (3.5) for the top and bottom.

Flex, unlikes Flash, rounds *all* positional number for better text readability and laying out.  If you were to change the inner rectangle height to 32, it would center perfectly.

Essentially, **don't use fractional positions**.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
<testVerticalCenter:diamond verticalCenter="0" height="100%"/>
```

How are you defining the namespace testVerticalCenter?

Comment: sorry, that's just the name of the group this is in. I'll edit to read local:diamond, assuming you place both in a same folder.

Comment: I never used local I am pretty sure you still have to define the namespace

Comment: I don't have flex 4 on this computer so I cant really test anything